# Poll and trigger a task in Storm Bolt

Tags: java, apache-storm, eventtrigger

I have a bolt that loads data from a file on disk (say `/blah/blah/movie_data.csv`) using a method (say `loadDataFromFile()`), and stores it in memory. This file gets refreshed every day by 10 am (guaranteed to get updated by 10 am). I want my bolt to reload all the data in the file once it has been refreshed (any time soon after 10 am).

How do I implement this? Should I poll `movie_data.csv` and check that timestamp is more recent than the last file load time, and if so, trigger the `loaddataFromFile()` method? Or could this be done using some form of `tick` tuples?

I don't need code/pseudo-code. Just some pointers on libraries/classes which might be relevant. I already looked at the `tick` tuple but it does not seem to be of help here since I want to refresh the file at a particular time, not every T seconds.

Is there a way for the bolt to receive a `tick` tuple at a scheduled time (say 10 am daily)? That way, I won't have to use polling to check if the file has been refreshed.

Comment: Who writes the file, do you have some influence on this process? I would personnally generate a MD5 or SHA1 of the file, put it in a datastore and dirty check it on a spout to launch the process if it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

That's depends if you using a Trident topology or not. If it's a Trident topology, you can implement a `storm.trident.spout.BatchSpoutExecutor` and a `BatchSpoutExecutor.BatchSpoutEmitter.` As I recall, check the Trident examples as they implements theses interfaces.

Hope that this will help.

Comment: Also, you can use a tick Tuple and refresh every 24 x 3600 s corresponding to refresh every day ;)

Comment: I am not using Trident. The 24x3600 won't work because if I start my topology at 7 am, then it will generate a tick tuple each day at 7 am, instead of 10 am.

Comment: Can you wait like an hour before processing? If you procecess the file at 11 am is it too late ? If not, maybe tick it each hours ? Also, when you start a topology, maybe use a sleep before starting it to get to the desired time, then wait a day with the tick ?